# Having trouble forming the correct CURL POST using PHP that contains fields and a file

Tags: php, file, curl, request, multipartform-data

Although I've found some similar questions, none of the answers I found so far have worked for me... I'm building a custom integration to a web-based DRM application, Vitrium, via the Vitrium API.  Part of this integration is to upload a document to Vitrium via the API. The API doc provides the required request format in `CURL`.  I'm writing in `PHP` and need to generate the correct `CURL` request in `PHP`. Here's what they are looking for:
[image: screenshot of CURL format]

I'm struggling with how to package and pass the multi-part form data and file, the `-F 'settings={some json}', and -F 'rawfile=@filename;type=pdf'` in my `PHP`, specifically Which `CURLOPT` parameters do I need to set, and how do i format this data in `PHP`? The file is uploaded in a form, the settings are defined as an array and then json_encoded.  Here is the code I have that formats and executes the `CURL`:

```
    $curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

where

```
  $headr = array("Content-Type: multipart\form-data",
                     "X-VITR-SESSION-TOKEN:".$vit_auth_resp['token'],
                     "X-VITR-ACCOUNT-TOKEN:".$vit_auth_resp['accountId'],
                     "accept: application/json"
                    );
```

and

```
$settings = array("Id"=>"",
                      "FolderId"=>$folder_id,
                      "PolicyId"=>"",
                      "FileName"=>$file_name,
                      "Title"=>$file_name,
                      "SkipPages"=>"",
                      "ExternalKey"=>"",
                      "VersionName"=>"Version 1",
                      "EnableVersionNotification"=>true);
    $params = array('settings'=>$settings,
                    'rawfile' => "@".$tmp_file.";type=pdf");
    $content = json_encode($params,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

and

```
$tmp_file = $_FILES['pdf_file']['tmp_name'];
```

I get an error:

> Bad Request - the request is badly formed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm way out of my league here and doing this as a favor for a client.

Comment: You're sending JSON data but have defined the content type as `multipart\form-data`? Which is it? (and it's `multipart/form-data` with a forward slash). Also, what does `$tmp_file` contain? Absolute file path? The actual file contents? If it's the actual contents, it won't work since JSON doesn't support binary data. What does the generated JSON look like?

Comment: The API doc specifies multipart form data.  Oddly, the API Doc shows the header with a back slash, when i tried the forward slash I got an error. $tmp_file = $_FILES['pdf_file']['tmp_name'].  The resulting json looks like this: {"settings":{"Id":"","FolderId":"87955e70-25a3-4537-9a93-2a96f6dac43e","PolicyId":"","FileName":"Engie-NE.pdf","Title":"Engie-NE.pdf","SkipPages":"","ExternalKey":"","VersionName":"Version 1","EnableVersionNotification":true},"rawfile":"@/tmp/phpW35z9V;type=pdf"}

Comment: @user3188091 When dealing with files and multipart/form-data, you should not JSON-encode the parameters. Instead, build the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS array with the correct structure.

Comment: Using `@file.txt` doesn't work in modern PHP, use [CurlFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) and treat it like any other field.

Comment: I tried sending the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS as an array as well and got the same error.  {POSTFIELDS = Array ( [settings] => Array ( [Id] => [FolderId] => 87955e70-25a3-4537-9a93-2a96f6dac43e [PolicyId] => [FileName] => Engie-NE.pdf [Title] => Engie-NE.pdf [SkipPages] => [ExternalKey] => [VersionName] => Version 1 [EnableVersionNotification] => 1 ) [rawfile] => @/tmp/phpD4jibO;type=pdf )}

Comment: @ syntax for file uploads in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is deprecated. Instead, you should use CURLFile to create a file field this should fix it good luck

Comment: I finally got it to work!!  Turns out Vitrium has a tool kit for php that I was able to pull from to create the required data payload, specifically the composebody() function.  https://www.vitrium.com/knowledgebase/guides/vitrium-security-api-guides/